# hotswap agent not working for jsp, css, js etc in a java web project

Tags: java, hotswap

I tried to setup hotswapagent with eclipse and tomcat from  http://www.hotswapagent.org. It worked fine for .java files but I can't make it to work for other resources. I even tried to create a hotswap-agent.properties file as mentioned in http://www.hotswapagent.org/quick-start/configuration but it did not work. My hotswap-agent.properties file looks like below

```
watchResources=${basedir}/src/main/resources
extraWebappContext=${basedir}/src/main/webapp/html
```

I even tried target folder instead of src but nothing works. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try with adding the following line to hotswap-agent.properties:

```
webappDir=c:/yourPath/src/main/webapp
```

Also follow these:

Configuration for [Netbeans](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hotswapagent/ydW5bQMwQqU)